# How to draw a triangle with line parallel inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

i need help with this triangle (Image 1), i don't know draw this in tex :c[image: Image 1]

Comment: Welcome! Although somebody may decide to draw your diagram for you from scratch, it isn't really fair to ask it. What have you tried so far? If you can post some code - ideally in the form of a Minimal Working Example - people will find it easier and more interesting to help (and will therefore be more likely to do so). (Very nearly almost) All questions on this site should include an MWE or an MnWE (if the question is about why it is *not*-Working an MWE wouldn't be possible or helpful, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\draw[-,thick] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (0,1.5);
\node [anchor = east] at (0,0) {O};
\node [anchor = east] at (0,1.5) {L};
\node [anchor = west] at (2,0) {T};
\node [anchor = east] at (0,0.75) {H};
\node [anchor = east] at (1,0.375) {h};
\node [anchor = south] at (0.5,0) {\textit{vt}};
\draw[-,very thick] (0,0) -- (0,1.5);
\draw[-,very thick] (1,0) -- (1,0.75);
\draw[{Bar[width=7mm][sep]Triangle[angle=20:10pt]}-{Triangle[angle=20:10pt][sep]Bar[width=7mm]},thick] (0,-0.25) -- node [anchor=north]{y} (2,-0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This requires \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

[image: tikz drawing]

Comment: You're welcome. I'm just learning tikz myself.

Comment: It works but if you change the size of the triangle you have to make many changes. Have a look at the sections _Relative and Incremental Coordinates_ and _Coordinate Calculations_ and learn how to compute coordinates from other coordinates. Also the 'pos=' option may be useful fro positioning the labels.

Comment: So, then, now's your chance to show how to do this properly. BTW if you reply to somebody in your reply, please use '@<name>' or the recipient may not notice your reply.

Answer (score 5):

And now a solution  with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}%,
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{dimen=middle, unit=2, labelsep=0.8ex, linejoin=1, arrowinset=0.12, arrowsize=4pt, tbarsize=10pt, PointSymbol=none, shortput=nab}
    \pstTriangle(0,0){O}(0,2){L}(2.5,0){T}
    \ncline[offset=-3ex, arrows=|<->|]{O}{T}\lput*{0}{$ y $}
    \psset{PointName=none, linewidth = 1.5pt, }
    \pstMiddleAB{O}{T}{I}
    \pstMiddleAB{L}{T}{K}
    \ncline{cc-cc}{O}{L}^{$ H $}
    \ncline{I}{K}^{$ h $}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{O}{I}^{$ vt $}
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

and one more TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label=left:$O$] (O);
    \coordinate[above=50mm of O, label= left:$L$] (L);
    \coordinate[right=50mm of O, label=right:$T$] (T);
    %
    \draw[thick](O) -- node[left] {$H$} (L) 
                    -- coordinate (h) (T)
                    -- node[pos=0.75,above]   {$vt$}  cycle;
    \draw[thick](h) -- node[left] {$h$}   (h |- O);
    \draw[{Bar[width=3mm].Latex[]}-{Latex[]Bar[width=3mm]}] 
        ($(O)-(0,4mm)$) -- node [fill=white] {$y$} ($(T)-(0,4mm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

% parameters
\def\height{3}
\def\width{5}
\def\widthSmall{2} % < \width

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.4,-0.4)(\fpeval{\width+0.43},\fpeval{\height+0.43})
  \pnodes(0,0){O}(0,\height){L}(\width,0){T}(\widthSmall,0){h}%
         (\widthSmall,\fpeval{(1-\widthSmall/\width)*\height}){H}
  \pspolygon(L)(T)(O)
  \uput[90](L){$L$}
  \uput[0](T){$T$}
  \uput[225](O){$O$}
  \psline(H)(h)
  \pcline[offset = -9pt]{|<*->|*}(O)(T)
  \ncput*{$y$}
 \psset{linestyle = none}
  \pcline[offset = 8pt](O)(L)
  \ncput{$H$}
  \pcline[offset = 6.5pt](O)(h)
  \ncput{$vt$}
  \pcline[offset = -6.5pt](H)(h)
  \ncput{$h$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is change the values of the parameters and the drawing will by adjusted accordingly.