# Triangle diagram made with tkz-euclide renders in TeX Live 2018 but not 2020

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, incompatibility, tkz-euclide

I have a triangle diagram that compiles and renders perfectly in Overleaf (TeX Live 2018):

[image]

Here is the code that compiles successfully:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\printanswers
\usepackage{gensymb} %for degree symbol
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,patterns,positioning,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} %For polygon nodes, see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

%Needed to resolve conflict between tkz-euclide and thmtools, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456029/thmtools-and-tkz-euclide-conflict
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
%\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%%% patch tkz-tools-base.tex
\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin % don't undef \@xa or thmtools will be upset
\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax\undef\@xb
\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin\undef\@ya
\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax\undef\@yb
\patchcmd{\tkz@Init}
 {\global\let\@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {\global\let\tkz@g@xa\tkz@init@xmin
  \global\let\tkz@g@xb\tkz@init@xmax
  \global\let\tkz@g@ya\tkz@init@ymin
  \global\let\tkz@g@yb\tkz@init@ymax}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\tkz@Grid}
 {(\@xa,\@ya)(\@xb,\@yb)}
 {(\tkz@g@xa,\tkz@g@ya)(\tkz@g@xb,\tkz@g@yb)}
 {}{}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
\part %from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314290/how-to-draw-a-triangle-with-line-parallel-inside
$\triangle ABC$ to $\triangle ADE$
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){D}
\tkzDefPoint(12,6){E}
\tkzLabelPoint[below right](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above right](E){$E$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
\tkzDrawSegment(D,E)
\tkzDefPoint(9,4.5){C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,E)\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDrawAltitude(A,D)(C)\tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelSegment[right](B,C){$y_1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[right](D,E){$y_2$}
\tkzLabelSegment[below](A,B){$x_1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[below](B,D){$x_2$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above](A,C){$z_1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above](C,E){$z_2$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.75,opacity=.4](A,B,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.75,opacity=.4](A,D,E)
\draw[{Bar[width=3mm].Latex[]}-{Latex[]Bar[width=3mm]}]($(D)-(0,1.5)$) -- node [fill=white] {$l$} ($(A)-(0,1.5)$);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
%\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

However if you change the TeX Live distribution from 2018 to 2020, it breaks the diagram and fails to render:

[image]

[image]

I learned from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529550/latex-cant-find-file-tkz-obj-angles-tex) that `\usetkzobj{all}` shouldn't be used with recent tkz-euclide. Commenting this line in the 2020 distribution fixes some but not all issues.

Here is a link to my Overleaf project, in case it helps:

[Overleaf MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/5442623619dcckrnqvrcyj)

You can try changing the version by going to Menu > TeX Live and seeing what happens. (Remember to uncomment `\usetkzobj{all}` if you switch TeX Live to 2018, or the diagram won't render properly.)

Any ideas what could be causing the incompatibility or incompatibilities? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for \tkzDrawXXXX seems to have changed and this affects your `\tkzDrawAltitude`. This here compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){D}
\tkzDefPoint(12,6){E}
\tkzLabelPoint[below right](D){$D$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above right](E){$E$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,D)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
\tkzDrawSegment(D,E)
\tkzDefPoint(9,4.5){C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,E)\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDrawAltitude(A,C,D)%<--- changed
\tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelSegment[right](B,C){$y_1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[right](D,E){$y_2$}
\tkzLabelSegment[below](A,B){$x_1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[below](B,D){$x_2$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above](A,C){$z_1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above](C,E){$z_2$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.75,opacity=.4](A,B,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.75,opacity=.4](A,D,E)
\draw[{Bar[width=3mm].Latex[]}-{Latex[]Bar[width=3mm]}]($(D)-(0,1.5)$) -- node [fill=white] {$l$} ($(A)-(0,1.5)$);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
%\draw (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The change from `\tkzDrawAltitude(A,D)(C)` to `\tkzDrawAltitude(A,C,D)` fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes Ulrike you are right. I hope to be able to participate more in the near future.  This syntax has been generalized.